# How to keep the value in the activity after coming back from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I created activity A > B > C.
Activity A pass an intent to B that will determine the value on B ListView.
The problem is that when I press the back button on C, the previous list on B is no longer there.
How do I keep the list value on B when the user press back button on C?

Comment: Show some code and explain more. If you are launching C from B and simply go back to B from C (by using the BACK button or calling `finish()` in C), B should be exactly as you left it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a static list variable to store/populate the list data. You can populate this list on activity A and use on activity B and since this variable will remain through entire android life cycle the list on activity B should not be affected when returning from activity C.

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{
//Inside Activity A
public static final List<MODEL> DATA_LIST = new ArrayList<MODEL>(); //here MODEL may be any type of object as required
//...
}
```

To use this variable on Activity B simply use ActivityA.DATA_LIST to reference to the list variable.